# what is the difference between getCornerPoints() and getBoundingBox() in TextBlock (android vision)

Tags: android, android-vision, text-recognition

I am confused about the what is the deffrence between getCornerPoints() and getBoundingBox() in TextBlock as they both return the coordinate of the corner points of the bounding box?? any body can clarify?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/TextBlock), `getBoundingBox()` returns a Rect that is axis-aligned. This is the area that the detected image takes up when projected in 2D space. Calling `getCornerPoints()`, on the other hand, accounts for perspective. As a result, it is not guaranteed to be a rectangle.  With different angles you may receive boundaries in the shape of parallelograms or trapezoids using this method.